# Vscode does not run

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Hi so i'm trying to run a code but nothing happen in the terminal I used to code but I stopped for a while now I need to code again and nothing, the easiest code in the world doesn't even run. Recently
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6qqt.png). If someone have any idea please

I cleaned up my computer by deleting a lot of files and I don't know if I missdelete something that could run in vscode

Comment: if you don't save the file it will never run, never use that top right triangle, use launch configs

Answer (score 1):

@fluffyweird here well as a beginner at Python this sort of problems happen quite frequently than you think No worries just follow up the following steps and if you have any questions you can reach me @fluffyweird :)...MY ADVICE: DON'T LET THIS MINOR PROBLEM DISCOURAGE YOU:)

SOLUTION: Since I can't make a video on this try and check this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AMAE0S_NzxE
Sometimes if you didn't add the python interpreter to your environment this happens :)

to check if you have installed python3 correctly try python3 -v :)

hope this helped

Comment: While the information in your link may solve the OP's question, answers that rely heavily on links are discouraged for [these reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/236527). Please consider updating your answer so that it is self-contained with the minimum amount of information required to execute this solution. Be sure to had any code if necessary. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You haven't saved the file yet, `Ctrl+S` save the file.

[image]

It is also recommended that you install the **[Pyhton](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python)** extension and then use `Run Python File` to execute the code.

[image]

*https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial*